# How to reach deterministic result with ML.NET multiclass classification?

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net

According to this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/github-issue-classification

> Initialize the _mlContext global variable with a new instance of MLContext with a random seed (seed: 0) for repeatable/deterministic results across multiple trainings. Replace the Console.WriteLine("Hello World!") line with the following code in the Main method:

```
_mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);
```

I tried to set the seed parameter to 0, 1 and null as well, but after I processed my data, builded and trained my model and call the following method, I always got different test metrics results.

```
MulticlassClassificationMetrics testMetrics = _mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Evaluate(_trainedModel.Transform(testDataView));
```

My data comes from my database, always with the same schema and data. My question is, how can I get deterministic result in ML.NET when I try to Evaluate a multiclass classification problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I've never had this problem using `seed: 0` - does your database query have an `order by` clause? Many database engines return rows in an undefined order unless you explicitly sort the rows.